# Add delay to MouseLeave Storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard, delay, mouseleave

I have a storyboard plays an animation when the `MouseLeave` is triggered for the particular control.

I want to introduce a delay of 500 millisecond after `MouseLeave` is triggered and check if the mouse is no longer over the control. Only then play the control. If the user has brought back the mouse over the control within 500 millisecond I need not play the storyboard animation. How to achieve this?

Comment: This can all be done in xaml. Just set the begintime of the storyboard to 00:00:00.5 and stop the storyboard if the mouse enters the control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code to Achieve your Requirement

```
private void UIElement_OnMouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var uiElement = sender as UIElement;
    uiElement.MouseLeave -= UIElement_OnMouseLeave;

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000); // or 500ms
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            if (!uiElement.IsMouseOver)
            {
                // Animation Code Goes Here;
            }
            uiElement.MouseLeave += UIElement_OnMouseLeave;
        });
    });
}
```

**OR** on Demand for Tarec

```
private readonly DispatcherTimer _dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer
{
    Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,1000),
};

_dispatcherTimer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
{
    _dispatcherTimer.Stop();
    if (!uIElement.IsMouseOver)
    {
        // Animation Code Goes Here;
    }
};

private void UIElement_OnMouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Reset Timer if Mouse Leave
    _dispatcherTimer.Stop();
    _dispatcherTimer.Start();
}
```

Comment: Casting an object with `as` and not null-checking it then is unacceptable. Also - I think that firing the method should be stopped/reseted everytime the mouse gets back to the uiElement. In your answer it is checked only once after exactly 1000ms from FIRST occurence of `OnMouseLeave`, so getting back and goint out with a mouse pointer within those 1000ms is ignored.

Comment: Thanks Mujahid for the nice answer, I couldn't have solved it better.

Comment: Why do we need `_dispatchTimer.Stop()` within OnMouseLeave when it is already stopped as part of the `Tick`? I didn't understand this part, could you please clarify?

Comment: i took this hack from [**How to Reset Timer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042312/how-to-reset-a-timer-in-c) this is the only difference in **Code 1** and **Code 2** as the timer restarts from 0 if the mouse leave instead of an intermediate value

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag `bool isMouseOver = true`. On `MouseLeave` set a flag to `false` and on `MouseEnter` set it to `true`. Create yourself a method that fires animation if `isMouseOver == false` and attach it to the timer with 500ms delay. The timer itself should be started/reseted on `MouseLeave` event and stopped on `MouseEnter`.

edit:
Of course you should use `IsMouseOver` property instead of custom flag if available.