# Behavior of AutoReset in Timers.Timer

Tags: .net, vb.net, timer

I have a timer that I have tied to the behavior of a UI element such that the UI element should auto-hide itself after 30s. After that point, it should only be made visible by explicitly calling `Show` on the element. I have implemented like this:

```
Private Sub myBtn_VisibleChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    _myBtn.Enabled = True
    _myTmr.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub myTmr_Elapsed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    _myBtn.Hide()
    _myBtn.Enabled = False
    _myTmr.Stop()
End Sub
```

`_myBtn` has the `VisibleChanged` event handled by the above method and `_myTmr` is setup this way:

```
Dim _myTmr As System.Timers.Timer = New System.Timers.Timer(30000.0)
_myTmr.AutoReset = False
_myTmr.Enabled = False
AddHandler _myTmr.Elapsed, AddressOf myTmr_Elapsed
```

I have a few questions about this setup:

1. Do I need to set `_myTmr.Enabled` to `False` on initialization or is that the default behavior? I'm unsure about this and I was unable to track down documentation that elucidated on this point.
2. How does the `AutoReset` property work? Does setting it to `False` mean that, `Elapsed` will only be raised once? After that happens, what will the value of the timer be? Will calling `Start` on `_myTmr` again, cause `Elapsed` to be raised again?
3. It appears that `myTmr_Elapsed` throws an `InvalidOperationException` because the `Elapsed` event is raised from a different thread than the UI thread. Is there a way to call `Hide` on the UI thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered a few things after doing some further research.

1. I shouldn't be using `System.Timers.Timer` for forms because it will not operate on the UI thread so any UI work that needs to be tied to the timer's `Elapsed` event will throw an `InvalidOperationException`. Rather, `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` should be used.
2. As I discovered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042312/how-to-reset-a-timer-in-c), setting `Enabled` to true will reset the timer, so claling `Start` should do so as well. Since the `Windows.Forms.Timer` has no `AutoReset` property, its behavior is somewhat mute at this point.

Comment: You might find that [Timers](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/threads/timers.shtml) has useful information for you.