# Exit application after x minutes of clipboard.gettext inactivity of Windows

Tags: c#, winforms, clipboard

It is possible that if you do not copy in me application for x minutes. That the program then closes to a few minutes? Can someone explain to me how I can handle that?

**EDIT**:
I wanted my application to close when no body is copying for instance in 2 minutes.

How can i solve my problem?

This is my code.

```
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        {
            const int WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD = 0x308;
            if (m.Msg == WM_DRAWCLIPBOARD)
            {
                // Kopieert en kijkt of het overeen komt met de list
                var text = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.UnicodeText);
                // als je gekopieert hebt reset de clipboard
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                {
                    timer1.Interval = 15000;
                    GetAnswer(Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.UnicodeText));
                    Clipboard.Clear();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can use timer, which is reset every time you get message. Exit software in timer event.

Comment: @Sinatr Could you perhaps show me an example to help me get started?

Answer (score 1):

1st drop a `Timer` component on your mainform, and set its `Interval` to as many minutes you want (the value is in milliseconds, so make sure you calculate it right)

Now Set the Enabled property of the timer to `true`

In the `Tick` event all you need to write is code to exit your application.

Now, everytime a copy/paste operation occurs, reset the timer like this

```
Timer1.Interval = xxx;
```

where xxx is the value in milliseconds

Resetting the timer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042312/how-to-reset-a-timer-in-c)

That should do it

in your case it will look something like this

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
{
    timer1.Enabled = false; // stop the timer

    // do code here that can take some time...
    GetAnswer(Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.UnicodeText));
    Clipboard.Clear();

    timer1.Interval = 15000; // reset the timer
    timer1.Enabled = true;   // and start it again
}
```

Comment: so I want an if else statement in which if the user does not copy for 5 minutes, the program closes automatically how can I best write that?

Comment: not by an `if else` statement, but by the method in this answer

Comment: Can you give a example to help me get started?

Comment: its all there, just start with this and if your stuck then show us what you have and then we can help you

Comment: I did this code i did a this.close but how can i reset the timer if i copied something. Because now my program is closing everytime after 10 secs
         ```private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }```

Comment: 10 seconds is not much time, I would set the Interval higher. You can reset the timer by the code shown in the answer. Do these 2 lines of code just before your code where you handle the copying

Comment: @rrwe I have edited my answer, with another method to reset the timer. It seems that this method would be saver to reset a timer

Comment: I almost succeeded. See my code at the top of my question. The few errors that are still there are when I copy again. The timer always stops at 30 seconds, so the code does not execute more than 2x. And if I copy at 13 seconds, it will only stop at 30 seconds. I want since I have my interval at 15000 that it stops at 28 sec.

Comment: @rrwe how long does the code takes that you execute when something is copied ? You could disable the timer at the start of your code, and then reset it to 15000 and enable it again at the end of your code

Comment: @rrwe I updated my answer with a possible solution for this