# How to reset a timer in C# winforms

Tags: c#, windows

I am working on a windows application where I start a timer .Everything is working but my reset of timer is working for me . It giving me error and timer does not reset

Coding is

```
        t = new System.Timers.Timer();
        t.Interval = 1000;
        t.Elapsed += OnTimeEvent;
        t.Start();
```

Reset Button Code

```
    private void btnrest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      
       t.Dispose();
        
       
        t = new System.Timers.Timer();
        lbltime.Text = "00.00.00";
    }
```

But it is not working
any help

Comment: Shouldn't you also set `Interval` and `Elapsed` in the reset button click handler?

Comment: Yes i did but not working !

Comment: _Doesn't work_ is not  a helpful problem description! - _It giving me error_ Then please do show that error!!!

Comment: Yes i try it but not working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset a timer in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042312/how-to-reset-a-timer-in-c)

Comment: The error is that timers not reset on button click . when i stop it and start again it start time where stop it . actually it start from zero but it does't not happen.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this :

```
private void btnrest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
   t.Stop();
   t.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Under reset click

```
t.Enabled = false;

t = new System.Timers.Timer();
t.Interval = 1000;
t.Elapsed += OnTimeEvent;
t.Start();  // by default on start Enabled = true
```

Comment: Adding these code start timer! nothing do anything .

Comment: Can you elaborate it more. The above code stops the timer and starts with new elapsed event on reset button. 
Is that what you expecting?