# Restart timer after Delay

Tags: c#

I use a timer initialized like this:

```
timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer
{
    Interval = monitorConfig.Interval
};

timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
```

In `Timer_Tick` event, after a certain condition I stop ther timer with

```
timer.Stop();
```

I do some stuff then i try to restart the timer after a delay like this:

```
var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

Task.Delay(timerDelay).ContinueWith((t) =>
{
    logger.Info("Starting Timer");
    timer.Start();
}, cancellationToken);
```

But the timer does not restart
I must be missing something
Thank you for your help

Comment: From looking over the internet it seems like you have 2 options: (1) Stop() and then Start() (2) AutoReset. Check out these links: (1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042312/how-to-reset-a-timer-in-c (2) https://www.delftstack.com/howto/csharp/reset-timer-in-csharp/

Comment: Hello,
I try to restart the timer  after a delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by using

```
System.Timers.Timer
```